# Outlook 2010 - Reopen messages

Tags: script, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation

The goal here is to compensate for the Executive use of Outlook 2010 at my employer.  Most of the bosses have developed a work process of opening a plethora of outlook messages and then using said open items as a checklist.

The issue here is this; if Outlook ever closes unexpectedly, they have no way to remember the list of "open messages."

The base flow I have for the script would be:

1. Periodically scan for open messages and save a list.
2. When Outlook first opens, check the above created list and auto open those items.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Here is not asking how to use Outlook 2010

Comment: This is on-topic. He's talking about creating a script or macro to do this work. This is clearly a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The "New Inspector" and "Item Close" events are all that need to be monitored. Since there is no reliably way to handle a "shutdown" in Outlook 2010, write these values immediately. The long-term Entry ID's should be saved. Then when restarting the Add-in, simply load appropriate inspectors with "Open" after first getting the items by the saved EIDs.

Happy coding.